# Unable to install anaconda on OS Catalina after changing username

Tags: python, anaconda, installation, macos-catalina

I upgraded my OS to Catalina then anaconda didn't work, so I deleted it and wanted to install it again.

However, my macOS username was *zoyie 1* which contains a space, leading to fail of installation.

Then I changed my username from *zoyie 1* to *ZongyuWu* and installed again.

The 64-Bit Graphical Installer still didn't work and gives me no error information, so I tried the 64-Bit Command Line Installer and get

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: Downloads
  channel url: file:///Users/zoyie 1/Downloads
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. Use `conda index /Users/zoyie 1/Downloads`, or create `noarch/repodata.json`
and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2`.
```

Does anyone know how to install anaconda on my mac now?

I can't use conda since I haven't installed anaconda.

I can't find ~/.condarac since I haven't installed anaconda.

There is no use by deleting lines about conda in ~/.bash_profile.

Same problem when trying to install miniconda.

Comment: Are you sure you removed Anaconda and Conda completely? It can be tricky, there are some files which are left behind.

Comment: I think I didn't remove them completely... I deleted the folder of anaconda and there are still something left somewhere I don't know. And I can't use the conda command to delete them since I can't install anaconda and conda...

Comment: At this point I would recommend hunting down and deleting every file related to Anaconda/Conda, and starting over.